# Sum column values if the rows are identical, keep unique rows (Pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Pyspark DF

```
col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d   col_f
-------------------------------------
val_1 |val_2 |val_3 |val_4 | integer_1
-------------------------------------
val_1 |val_2 |val_3 |val_4 | integer_2
-------------------------------------
val_5 |val_6 |val_7 |val_8 | integer_3
-------------------------------------
val_1 |val_2 |val_3 |val_4 | integer_4
-------------------------------------
```

The dataframe I'm trying to generate is:

```
col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d   col_f
-------------------------------------
val_1 |val_2 |val_3 |val_4 | integer_1 + integer_2 + integer_4
-------------------------------------
val_5 |val_6 |val_7 |val_8 | integer_3
-------------------------------------
```

The goal is to sum up all col_f values if the col_a, col_b, col_c, and col_c are equal, but also to keep other rows that are unique.

How can this be achieved? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this sample `DF`:

```
>>> df
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|col_f|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|    d|    1|
|    a|    b|    c|    d|    2|
|    j|    h|    k|    l|    3|
|    a|    b|    c|    d|    4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

You can `groupBy.agg`, in a very similar fashion as you would do in `pandas`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

g = ['col_a','col_b','col_c','col_d']
df.groupBy(g).agg(F.sum('col_f').alias("total_col_f")).show()
```

prints:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d|total_col_f|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
|    a|    b|    c|    d|          7|
|    j|    h|    k|    l|          3|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

In your case it would look something like (pandas):

```
df.groupby([col_a,col_b,_col_c,col_d]).sum()
```

Or with [PySpark](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-groupby-explained-with-example/):

```
df.groupBy(col_a,col_b,_col_c,col_d).sum(col_f)
```

Comment: I am using Pyspark, I will update the question to reflect it clearly.

Comment: The Pyspark groupby syntax is nearly identical : https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-groupby-explained-with-example/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try that out!
EDIT: if it works, I'll accept the answer.